# Logging in gunicorn log file is not detailed

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gunicorn

I'm setting log level to 'debug' which I recall is the most verbose, however I'm only getting lines like this, even when an exception is thrown:

```
[2018-04-18 22:08:21 +0000] [23394] [DEBUG] POST /json
```

My startup command is this:

```
gunicorn  --log-level debug --error-logfile gunicorn_error.log  -D -b 0.0.0.0:5000 forward_to_es:app
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you create a gunicorn config file. for example:

```
# /path-to-your-project/gunicorn_conf.py
bind = '0.0.0.0:8811'
worker_class = 'sync'
loglevel = 'debug'
accesslog = '/var/log/gunicorn/access_log_yourapp'
acceslogformat ="%(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s %(r)s %(s)s %(b)s %(f)s %(a)s"
errorlog =  '/var/log/gunicorn/error_log_yourapp'
```

In the [documentation](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html) you may find all possible identifiers for your access log.

Then just do

```
/path-to-your-project/gunicorn -c gunicorn_conf.py forward_to_es:app
```

This way you may have one or more configurations or even create various logs depending on the configuration you are trying.

Comment: In your example, you're binding directly to a port, how would you modify your example when gunicorn is binding through a unix socket? For example, in my `gunicorn.service ` file, I have: `ExecStart=/path/to/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /- --workers 3 --bind unix:/var/log/gunicorn/myproj.sock myproj.wsgi:application` - how I can I use a config file in this case?

Comment: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#server-socket `bind = 'unix:/some/path'`